# How to debug GCC/LD linking process for STL/C++

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, linker, embedded

I'm working on a bare-metal cortex-M3 in C++ for fun and profit. I use the STL library as I needed some containers. I thought that by simply providing my allocator it wouldn't add much code to the final binary, since you get only what you use.

I actually didn't even expect any linking process at all with the STL
(giving my allocator), as I thought it was all template code.

I am compiling with `-fno-exception` by the way.

Unfortunately, about 600KB or more are added to my binary. I looked up what symbols are included in the final binary with nm and it seemed a joke to me. The list is so long I won't try and past it. Although there are some weak symbols.

I also looked in the .map file generated by the linker and I even found the scanf symbols

```
.text
0x000158bc       0x30   /CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libc.a(sscanf.o)
0x000158bc                __sscanf
0x000158bc                sscanf
0x000158bc                _IO_sscanf
```

And:

```
$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm binary | grep scanf
000158bc T _IO_sscanf
0003e5f4 T _IO_vfscanf
0003e5f4 T _IO_vfscanf_internal
000164a8 T _IO_vsscanf
00046814 T ___vfscanf
000158bc T __sscanf
00046814 T __vfscanf
000164a8 W __vsscanf
000158bc T sscanf
00046814 W vfscanf
000164a8 W vsscanf
```

How can I debug this? For first I wanted to understand what exactly GCC is using for linking (I'm linking through GCC). I know that if symbol is found in a text segment, the
whole segment is used, but still that's too much.

Any suggestion on how to tackle this would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using GCC's `-v` and `-Wl,-v` options will show you the linker commands (and version info of the linker) being used.

Which version of GCC are you using?  I made some changes for GCC 4.6 (see [PR 44647](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44647) and [PR 43863](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43863)) to reduce code size to help embedded systems.  There's still an outstanding enhancement request ([PR 43852](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43852)) to allow disabling the inclusion of the IO symbols you're seeing - some of them come from the verbose terminate handler, which prints a message when the process is terminated with an active exception.  If you're not using execptions then some of that code is useless to you.

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.6.3 from Code Sourcery.

The -Wl,-v option was very useful. Along the flags I passed to the linker, it also included the following 
     -lstdc++ -lm --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group

now I have to understand why, and how to remove them. Especially the gcc_eh which I suppose stands for exception handling. Any suggestions or reading about this?

Comment: If you link with `gcc` instead of `g++` then it won't pass `-lstdc++` to the linker, and that might also remove the need for `-lgcc -lgcc_eh` (I don't remember offhand, I'd have to check) but if you don't use any code from those libs then it shouldn't increase the executable size anyway - the verbose terminate handler in libstdc++ is probably what pulls in the unwanted code

Comment: If I use gcc it won't find the _List_node_base::_M_hook symbol.Passing -lstdc++ includes everything else.
To narrow down the problem I tried linking directly with ld adding those flags one by one. It's missing __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0 in libstdc++.a(list.o):(..._List_node_base7_M_hookE)
which then links to libc (memcpy and other), which then links everything else. It's a big chain and a PITA. I just wanted a container. :-)
I also figured that,since I have a global object, it needs  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 which I didn't expect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook` is not inline, it's defined in `libstdc++.a`, but the file it's in (`list.cc`) is pretty small and I'm surprised it requires the unwind support if you've disabled exceptions ... strange.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about the STL, it is about the Standard library.

The STL itself is *pure* (in a way), but the Standard Library also includes all those streams packages and it seems that you also managed to pull in the `libc` as well...

The problem is that the Standard Library has never been meant to be picked apart, so there might not have been much concern into re-using stuff from the C Standard Library...

You should first try to identify which files are pulled in when you compile (using `strace` [for example](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)), this way you can verify that you only ever use *header-only* files.

Then you can try and remove the linking that occurs. There are options to pass to gcc to precise that you would like a standard library-free build, something like `--nostdlib` for example, however I am not well versed enough in those to instruct you exactly here.

Comment: I am already passing -nostdlib to the compiler, along with -fno-exception, but it seems not to work.