# Compiling static C program doesn't find curl functions, even though linked

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to compile a C program statically. I tried adding "-static" option to the command line, but still get erros.
This is the command line.

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe -lcurl -static -L"C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" -lregex -lsqlite3 -lssl -ljansson -liphlpapi -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -w -mwindows
```

(The "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" path includes the libcurl.a)

**Errors:**

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x581): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x5a6): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x6e7): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x700): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x713): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_free_all'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x71c): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0xd5a): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_strerror'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x113a): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_formadd'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x11fb): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x1214): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_formfree'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz3KeYh.o:main.c:(.text+0x137c): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_strerror'
```

There are also other library errors in the same one.

**Errors:**

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a(systre.o):(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `tre_regcomp'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a(systre.o):(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `tre_regfree'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a(systre.o):(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `tre_regerror'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a(systre.o):(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `tre_regexec'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x2a5): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `__imp_ntohs'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x3e3): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x402): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x413): undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x465): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x48f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj):(.text+0x4fd): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
```

***-v Output:***

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-13.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-static' '-LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib' '-w' '-mwindows' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mwindows -mtune=generic -march=nocona -w -version -o C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUBzLLV.s
GNU C17 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) version 13.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 13.2.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version 4.2.0-p12, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

warning: MPFR header version 4.2.0-p12 differs from library version 4.2.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/mingw64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/mingw64/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: f9bd18fc84ad3f3a3728d580196f7356
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-static' '-LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib' '-w' '-mwindows' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -W -o C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cctKVUpC.o C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUBzLLV.s
GNU assembler version 2.41 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.41
COMPILER_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main.exe' '-static' '-LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib' '-w' '-mwindows' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'main.'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmIlYkr.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgdi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lcomdlg32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep --subsystem windows -Bstatic -o main.exe C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cctKVUpC.o -lcurl -lregex -lsqlite3 -lssl -ljansson -liphlpapi -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtend.o
```

***"-Wl,-v" Output:***

```
collect2 version 13.2.0
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe -plugin C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccktir8z.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgdi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lcomdlg32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep --subsystem windows -Bstatic -o main.exe C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7Vdy7N.o -lcurl -lregex -lsqlite3 -lssl -ljansson -liphlpapi -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -v -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtend.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.41
```

***"-Wl,--verbose" Output:***

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.41
  Supported emulations:
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-x86-64)
SEARCH_DIR("=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/mingw64/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Make the virtual address and file offset synced if the alignment is
     lower than the target page size. */
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
    *(.text)
    *(SORT(.text$*))
     *(.text.*)
     *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.glue_7)
    . = ALIGN(8);
       /* Note: we always define __CTOR_LIST__ and ___CTOR_LIST__ here,
          we do not PROVIDE them.  This is because the ctors.o startup
          code in libgcc defines them as common symbols, with the
          expectation that they will be overridden by the definitions
          here.  If we PROVIDE the symbols then they will not be
          overridden and global constructors will not be run.
          See PR 22762 for more details.

          This does mean that it is not possible for a user to define
          their own __CTOR_LIST__ and __DTOR_LIST__ symbols; if they do,
          the content from those variables are included but the symbols
          defined here silently take precedence.  If they truly need to
          be redefined, a custom linker script will have to be used.
          (The custom script can just be a copy of this script with the
          PROVIDE() qualifiers added).
          In particular this means that ld -Ur does not work, because
          the proper __CTOR_LIST__ set by ld -Ur is overridden by a
          bogus __CTOR_LIST__ set by the final link.  See PR 46.  */
       ___CTOR_LIST__ = .;
       __CTOR_LIST__ = .;
       LONG (-1); LONG (-1);
       KEEP (*(.ctors));
       KEEP (*(.ctor));
       KEEP (*(SORT_BY_NAME(.ctors.*)));
       LONG (0); LONG (0);
       /* See comment about __CTOR_LIST__ above.  The same reasoning
          applies here too.  */
       ___DTOR_LIST__ = .;
       __DTOR_LIST__ = .;
       LONG (-1); LONG (-1);
       KEEP (*(.dtors));
       KEEP (*(.dtor));
       KEEP (*(SORT_BY_NAME(.dtors.*)));
       LONG (0); LONG (0);
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
    /* ??? Why is .gcc_exc here?  */
     *(.gcc_exc)
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
     KEEP (*(.gcc_except_table))
  }
  /* The Cygwin32 library uses a section to avoid copying certain data
     on fork.  This used to be named ".data".  The linker used
     to include this between __data_start__ and __data_end__, but that
     breaks building the cygwin32 dll.  Instead, we name the section
     ".data_cygwin_nocopy" and explicitly include it after __data_end__. */
  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __data_start__ = . ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data2)
    *(SORT(.data$*))
    KEEP(*(.jcr))
    __data_end__ = . ;
    *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
  }
  .rdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.rdata)
             *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __rt_psrelocs_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc))
    __rt_psrelocs_end = .;
  }
  __rt_psrelocs_size = __rt_psrelocs_end - __rt_psrelocs_start;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  .eh_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame*))
  }
  .pdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP(*(.pdata*))
  }
  .xdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP(*(.xdata*))
  }
  .bss BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __bss_start__ = . ;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    __bss_end__ = . ;
  }
  .edata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.edata)
  }
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug$S)
    *(.debug$T)
    *(.debug$F)
     *(.drectve)
     *(.note.GNU-stack)
     *(.gnu.lto_*)
  }
  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
        See pep.em:sort_sections.  */
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$2))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$3))
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$4))
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$5)
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$6))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$7))
  }
  .CRT BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___crt_xc_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XC*)))  /* C initialization */
    ___crt_xc_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xi_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XI*)))  /* C++ initialization */
    ___crt_xi_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xl_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XL*)))  /* TLS callbacks */
    /* ___crt_xl_end__ is defined in the TLS Directory support code */
    ___crt_xp_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XP*)))  /* Pre-termination */
    ___crt_xp_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xt_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XT*)))  /* Termination */
    ___crt_xt_end__ = . ;
  }
  /* Windows TLS expects .tls$AAA to be at the start and .tls$ZZZ to be
     at the end of the .tls section.  This is important because _tls_start MUST
     be at the beginning of the section to enable SECREL32 relocations with TLS
     data.  */
  .tls BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___tls_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(.tls$AAA))
    KEEP (*(.tls))
    KEEP (*(.tls$))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.tls$*)))
    KEEP (*(.tls$ZZZ))
    ___tls_end__ = . ;
  }
  .endjunk BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* end is deprecated, don't use it */
    PROVIDE (end = .);
    PROVIDE ( _end = .);
     __end__ = .;
  }
  .rsrc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) : SUBALIGN(4)
  {
    KEEP (*(.rsrc))
    KEEP (*(.rsrc$*))
  }
  .reloc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.reloc)
  }
...
}
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: mode i386pep
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o succeeded
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o succeeded
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o
attempt to open C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDaML7J.o succeeded
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDaML7J.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcurl.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcurl.a
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libregex.a)systre.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libsqlite3.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libsqlite3.a
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libsqlite3.a)sqlite3.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libssl.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libssl.a
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)load.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)memory.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)strbuffer.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)strconv.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)utf.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)value.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)error.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)hashtable.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libjansson.a)hashtable_seed.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libiphlpapi.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libiphlpapi.a
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-e_aes.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-encode.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-evp_enc.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-evp_fetch.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-evp_lib.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-evp_utils.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-pmeth_gn.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-pmeth_lib.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-signature.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-context.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-core_algorithm.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-core_fetch.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-core_namemap.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-cryptlib.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ex_data.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-init.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-initthread.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-mem.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-mem_sec.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-o_str.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-params.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-params_dup.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-provider_child.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-provider_conf.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-provider_core.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-provider_predefined.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-self_test_core.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-threads_win.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-trace.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-x86_64cpuid.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-aesni-gcm-x86_64.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-cbc128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ccm128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-cfb128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ctr128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-gcm128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ghash-x86_64.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ocb128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-ofb128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-wrap128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-xts128.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-o_names.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-obj_dat.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-obj_lib.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-obj_xref.obj
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libcrypto.a)libcrypto-lib-defn_cache.obj
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a succeeded
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-gccmain.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-natstart.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-wildcard.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-dllargv.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-_newmode.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-tlssup.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-xncommod.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-cinitexe.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-merr.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-CRT_fp10.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-mingw_helpers.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-pseudo-reloc.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-usermatherr.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-xtxtmode.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-crt_handler.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-tlsthrd.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-tlsmcrt.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-pseudo-reloc-list.o
(C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmingw32.a)lib64_libmingw32_a-pesect.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc.a succeeded
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc.a
(C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc.a)_chkstk_ms.o
(C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc.a)_ctors.o
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libgcc_eh.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc_eh.a succeeded
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0\libgcc_eh.a
attempt to open C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libmoldname.a succeeded
```

***Using `-l:libcurl.a`:***

```
C:\Users\__\testing>gcc main.c -o main.exe -static -l:libcurl.a -lregex -lsqlite3 -lssl -ljansson -liphlpapi -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -w -mwindows
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDreVpm.o:main.c:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDreVpm.o:main.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
...
```

Comment: Use -v options to the compiler and the linker to gather more info.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I tried it, what exactly should I look for?

Comment: There is no -v for the linker used in there. Try -Wl,-v.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI On gcc? `gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-Wl'; did you mean '-W'?`

Comment: `warning: MPFR header version 4.2.0-p12 differs from library version 4.2.1.` looks suspicious.

Comment: You need `-Wl,-v` exactly as written. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592289/how-to-debug-gcc-ld-linking-process-for-stl-c

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Oh, sorry, my bad, edited.

Comment: My bad,  needs -Wl,--verbose.

Comment: I am far from an expert in this, but I seem to recall that the `__imp` prefix seen in the errors above indicate that it's trying to link to the lib file for the dll, and not the static library. You may want to try `-l:libcurl.a` instead of `-lcurl`.

Comment: Added "`-Wl,--verbose`" to last one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Hello, I tried it, I can't see much of a difference, but I edited the question with using the "`-l:libcurl.a`"

Comment: @500-InternalServerError this does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: yeah, I checked our own make files here, and we also do simply `-lcurl`, but those are for Linux, so I'm out of ideas. (yes, we do link curl statically with no issues).

Comment: So it opens libcurl.a from the place  it is supposed to. Now you need to figure out what this library is, a static library or an import library.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I wonder why my doesn't. Could be because I'm developing on Windows, trough MSYS2 -> mingw64 -> gcc.